# R: how to check if a vector is found in another vector of different length without using %in%

Tags: r

```
vector_1 = c(4,3,5,1,2)
vector_2 = c(3,1)

output:
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

how do I get the output just by using basic operators/loops without using the operator %in% or any functions in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without "functions" is a bit vague, since virtually anything in R is a function. Probably that's an assignment and a `for` loop is wanted.

```
res <- logical(length(vector_1))

for (i in seq_along(vector_1)) {
  for (j in seq_along(vector_2)) {
    if (vector_1[i] == vector_2[j])
    res[i] <- TRUE
  }
}

res
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

However, that's not very R-ish where you rather want to do something like

```
apply(outer(vector_1, vector_2, `==`), 1, \(x) x[which.max(x)])
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

*Data:*

```
vector_1 <- c(4, 3, 5, 1, 2)
vector_2 <- c(3, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

See `` match.fun(`%in%`) ``

```
match(vector_1,vector_2, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

Comment: I don't know how to escape the backtick  to write code that includes ` backticks :)

Comment: You can use triple backticks to 'surround' single backticks (I've edited your answer to show how, I hope that's ok with you). I was going to add the answer `!is.na(match(vector_1, vector_2))` but your method is clearer/more 'legit' (+1)

Answer (score 1):

One way with `sapply()` -

```
sapply(vector_1, function(x) any(x == vector_2))
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```